# SharedPreferences загрузка при первом запуске

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Есть layout **settings.xml** с кастомными настройками

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.lar1ch.test.CustomPreference
        android:id="@+id/custom_settings_item1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:title="Title 1"
        android:defaultValue="120"
        android:key="item1key"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Значение в **SharedPreferences** сохраняется так

```
public void saveData()
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = getContext().getSharedPreferences("SP", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt(mKey, mValue);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Но значения не записываются в SharedPreferences при первом запуске, только после открытия настроек. Пробовал добавить в **MainActivity** в **onCreate()**

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, "SP", MODE_PRIVATE, R.layout.settings, false);
```

Но приложение вылетает с ошибкой

```
11-08 08:35:39.271 E/AndroidRuntime(23722): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.preference.LinearLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lar1ch.test-v82GnmbfEzQxHStMUYcivQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lar1ch.test-v82GnmbfEzQxHStMUYcivQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
```

Как сделать, чтоб значение записывались в **SharedPreferences** при первом запуске приложения?

Comment: Что-то у вас разметка подозрительная и Андроид на неё ругается - если она используется в `PreferenceFragment/Activity` то в ней нельзя использовать обычные вью, только `Preference`. Почитайте гайд: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#DefiningPrefs

Comment: Нет, она используется просто в Activity. Всё работает, сохраняется... Единственное, что не получается сделать, чтоб настройки при первом запуске из android:defaultValue записывались в SharedPreferences

Comment: А, ну тогда `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues` не поможет - ему нужен `xml` настроек, а не обычный лейаут. При запросе любого значения из `SharedPreferences` вы и так в обязательном порядке передаёте дефолтное значение вторым аргументом, которое возвращается обратно, когда по такому ключу ничего не записано. То есть для случая из вопроса `int val = sp.getInt("item1key", 120)` - будет получено `120`, если ещё не было записано другое значение. Либо сделайте нормальный экран настроек по гайду.